# QT QML ui button on clicked function not working and it generates some issues

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

I, want to configure the QML button click. I'm facing some issues while following the official document to this scenario for the button click. If anyone knows how to do this correctly please put your answer.

I'm getting below IDE error in my QML file

[image]

**Test_One.ui.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    property alias button1: button1
    property alias button: button

    Pane {
        id: pane
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 138
            y: 168
            text: qsTr("Click Me")
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            x: 138
            y: 253
            text: qsTr("TEST")
        }
    }
}
```

**Test_One.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Test_One {
    button1.onClicked: {
        console.log("--------------- button1 clicked ---------------")
    }
    button.onClicked: {
        console.log("--------------- button clicked ---------------")
    }
}
```

Again please anyone, know how to do this correctly please post your answer. It will be more helpful.

Thank You!

Comment: The component's name is the file name without extension. You put `Test_One` components inside `Test_One.qml` and that creates recursion.

Comment: I didn't get that can you please explain to me. @folibis

Comment: Please see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#naming-custom-qml-object-types) example